# Python - Using arange to plot points leading to duplicate points

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am attempting to create an array of 2D points from a set of vertices by using the arange function and numpy.stack to populate a list and then convert it into an array at the end.

I then take these points and plot them in matplotlib in a second program. Unfortunately instead of being a series of lines forming boxes as I'd expected it seems many of the lines have been double-counted or not counted at all.

The code to write the array is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

objectradius = 4
objectspace = 2     #Must be half the objectradius


boundingvertex = [180,180],[180,-180],[-180,-180],[-180,180]    #The vertices of the corners of the objects They must be given in clockwise or anti-clockwise order  
box1vertex = [-120,-120],[-120,-80],[40,-80],[40,-120]
box2vertex = [-120,0],[-160,0],[-160,160],[-120,160]
box3vertex = [-80,-40],[-40,-40],[-40,120],[-80,120]
box4vertex = [80,-120],[160,-120],[160,80],[80,80]

vertexlist = boundingvertex + box1vertex + box2vertex + box3vertex + box4vertex
vertices = np.asarray(vertexlist) #Converts vertices list to array
segments = []

for i in range (5): #For each object
    objectnum = i + 1
    for k in range(4):  #For each corner vertex
        start = vertices[objectnum + k] 
        end = vertices[objectnum + (k+1)%4]
        if start[0] == end[0]:  #If they have equal x
            if start[1]<end[1]: #If the start point is bigger (more positive) than the end it will fail, so we have to reorder the points
                #print(i,k)
                #print(start,end,"equal x")
                templist = np.arange(start[1],end[1],objectspace)   #Evenly spaces points between the two points
                pointnumber = np.size(templist)
                if pointnumber == 0:
                    print(i,k,"went wrong here")
                    break
                coord = np.full(pointnumber,start[0])   #Makes an equally long array of the x co-ordinate
                newlist = np.stack((templist,coord),axis=-1)    #Takes the templist points and adds the x co-ordinate onto them.
                segments.append(newlist)
                #print (segments)
            else:
                #print(i,k)
                #print(start,end,"equal x")
                templist = np.arange(end[1],start[1],objectspace)
                pointnumber = np.size(templist)
                if pointnumber == 0:
                    print(i,k,"went wrong here")
                    break
                coord = np.full(pointnumber,start[0])
                newlist = np.stack((templist,coord),axis=-1)
                segments.append(newlist)
                #print (segments)
        else:
            if start[0]<end[0]:
                #print(i,k)
                #print(start,end,"equal x")
                templist = np.arange(start[0],end[0],objectspace)
                pointnumber = np.size(templist)
                if pointnumber == 0:
                    print(i,k,"went wrong here")
                    break
                coord = np.full(pointnumber,start[1])
                newlist = np.stack((coord,templist),axis=-1)
                segments.append(newlist)
                #print (segments)
            else:
                #print(i,k)
                #print(start,end,"equal x")
                templist = np.arange(end[0],start[0],objectspace)
                pointnumber = np.size(templist)
                if pointnumber == 0:
                    print(i,k,"went wrong here")
                    break
                coord = np.full(pointnumber,start[1])
                newlist = np.stack((coord,templist),axis=-1)
                segments.append(newlist)
                #print (segments)

segments.append(vertices)
finalpoints = np.asarray(segments)
```

From this code I copy pasted the array values from each element of finalpoints into a text file which is then read by the second program to plot the points.

When the second program is run and the points are plotted the result looks like this [sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP4O7.png). Clearly the vertices are being plotted correctly but the arange points have not. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you really want help you need to simplify the problem.  See the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: On a cursory glance, shouldn't it be `objectnum*4+k` in the start and end indices of the vertex. Can you explain what exactly are you trying to do and remove the redundant code?